# Create a Navigation Bar with same view

Tags: ios, swift

I recently started developing with swift and after several hours of research I did not find my answer to my problem , that's why I come here, hoping to find a kind soul who can help me :).

So I would like to create a view that will be used more than once from a tab bar.
So I created a navigation bar like this in ViewController.swift file:

```
var tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = false
    tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, screenSize.width, 50)

    var controllers:[AppGridVC] = []
    for index in 0..<4 {
        var tab = AppGridVC(nibName: "AppGridVC", bundle: nil)
        tab.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: namePage[index], image: nil, tag: (index+1))
        controllers.append(tab)
    }
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers

    self.view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
```

**AppGridVC** is the page I want to display each tab in the tab bar. it's instantiated like this: `class AppGridVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource` and they are swift file and xid file.

**namePage** is an array that contains each title of tab

When I execute the program, the first tab shows me the contained but when I select another tab my application stops. I have no error message. The AppDelegate.swift file is open and the first line of the file is highlighted in green with annotated next : *Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS*

I can not identify my error (probably due to a lack of knowledge :)). Can someone help me ?

Thx

Comment: Your tab bar controller is probably being deallocated. You shouldn't really add a tab bar controller's view as a subview of your controller's view; that's not good practice. It should probably be the window's root view controller, but it's not clear from your question what the purpose of ViewController is. Also, you should edit your question -- you talk about a navigation bar, but there's nothing in your code about a navigation bar.

Comment: If this code resides in some method and you don't have a strong pointer points to it, then it's probably is deallocated. When you tap on another tab, tab bar tries to call a delegate method on the deallocated object like @rdelmar said.

Comment: If you want to prevent this from happening, you could have `var tabBarController: UITabBarController!` as an instance variable for this class. Then you assign your newly created `tabBarController` in the code above to `self.tabBarController`. This will prevent it from being deallocated. But the better way is that you shouldn't let this class manages the tab bar controller, since it will be one of the sub view controllers for this tab bar controller. Can't you just create tab bar controller in the storyboard and drag _view controller segues_ to this view controller?

Comment: Thanx you all.
@rdelmar sorry for misunderstand, i spoke of a tab bar and not a navigation bar.

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit I prefer to develop to use the storyboard ;)